# null pointer exception while checking string

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In my application I want to perform an action by checking a condition. I have two strings odate and indate. These strings take data from database. If there is no data in both the strings i want to show an alert dialog box. If either indate or odate have any value in it I want to move to next activity. There is a problem occurs when I am trying to check "if indate and odate equal to null" perform a function. but when it is actually null it shows a null pointer exception instead of entering the else clause. 
Here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_iem);


getdate();
invorder();
orderheader();

}
  private void orderheader() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try{
      DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select order_date from order_header where cust_code="+code, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()){

             odate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("order_date"));
                Log.v("orderheader", odate);

            }}
     catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
       }        
}
private void invorder() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
     DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select inv_date from inv_header where cust_code="+code, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()){

             indate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("inv_date"));
                Log.v("invheader", indate);

            }
     catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
       }    
        }
public void onBackPressed(){ 
    gettime();
    String m = "";
    if(odate.matches("") && indate.matches("")){

        DatabaseHelper databasecontroller = new     DatabaseHelper(Menu_iem.this);
         databas.put("rscode","0");
         databasecontroller.enterreason(databas);
        Intent inn= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
         startActivity(inn);
    }
    else{
    spinneralert();
    }
 DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());  
        List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();  

        // Creating adapter for spinner  
      final  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);  
        final Spinner sp = new Spinner(Menu_iem.this);
        sp.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner  
        String str = "PLEASE SELECT YOUR REASON ";
        sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);  
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Menu_iem.this);
        builder.setTitle(str);
        builder.setView(sp);
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 DatabaseHelper databasecontroller = new DatabaseHelper(Menu_iem.this);
                 databas.put("rscode",rc);
                 databasecontroller.enterreason(databas);
                Intent inn= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                 startActivity(inn);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  
    try{
         DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new    DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select reason_code from reason_master where reason_name =" +label, null);


        while (c.moveToNext()){

         rc  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("reason_code"));

        }
}catch (SQLiteException se ) {
Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
   }

    }
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }  
}
}
```

I tried other questions but nothing helped me. Please help to sort out this.

EDIT 
here is my error log

```
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304): Process: com.example.sellatease,     PID: 4304
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304): java.lang.NullPointerException:   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()'     on a null object reference
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:759)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:510)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
 04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1148)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
 04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 04-07 16:52:23.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: `indate.matches("")` not like this do like `if(indate==null)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(odate.matches("") && indate.matches("")){
```

Here you are matching the string with empty. First make sure those string are not null and then check wether its having any value or not.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.matches(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
"

Comment: @Bivin crashOveride has added the sample code what i mean in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(odate) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(indate) {
      // go to activity
   } else {
      // show dialog
   }
```

You can read more about TextUtils  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html

Comment: Note that `TextUtils.isEmpty(String)` returns `false` for space-only Strings

Comment: Yes. Space only strings are considered empty

Comment: I used this too.but no change

Comment: check the edit. Have changed the code to fit your scenario

Comment: I tried the edited code. when using this i get error even when i have value in those variables.I have edited my question with my error log.could you please take a look?

Comment: I think String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  This is causing the nullpointer exception. Check if parent.getItemAtPosition(position) is null then do to String

Comment: I just disabled the onclick listener of spinner and run the code again.but still I am having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

change  `if(odate.matches("") && indate.matches("")){` to

```
if((odate == null || odate.trim.length() < 2) &&  (indate == null || indate.trim.length() < 2)){
```

ofcourse you can change the number 2 to whatever length you need.

## Update 1:

From your error log, I think the error is that the variable 'label' is null in line

```
final  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);
```

Check whether the dbHelper functions returns null to label, and add a checking before using labels like

```
If(labels !=null){//create adapter here}
```

Comment: Still I am getting null pointer exception.the else clause is n't exicuting

Comment: I made this change.but still I am having the same error.why it is so?

Comment: @Bivin do it seems atleast one of the items of List 'labels' is null.

Comment: Try debugging and check all values of list labels. Or You can use for(String item:labels){ Log.w("Item", "Value : " + String.valueOf(item);}  just below null check

Answer (score 0):

```
if(odate.matches("") && indate.matches("")){
}
```

replace your above code with

```
if(odate!=null && indate!=null){
     if(odate.matches("") && indate.matches("")){
      }
}else{
   // you getting null object 
}
```

it will first check if your string object is null if its not null than after that it will try to invoke mathes function.

Comment: It remains in the same page

Comment: its because your object is null

Comment: Yes.when it is null I want to show an alert dialog .otherwise move to the next action.